# Gradle - Groovy vs Gradle - Kotlin vs Maven for Java Spring Boot web application project on IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle

I am so new to Spring so could anyone please explain the differences between the three: Gradle - Groovy vs Gradle - Kotlin vs Maven?
Even though my question is specifically for a Java web application project, I also want to hear your opinions in general about these three.
[image]

Comment: The first two are gradle using groovy or kotlin syntax respectively for configuration. The other is, well, maven.

Comment: One uses Maven to manage dependencies, and the other two use Gradle to manage dependencies, either with the build files using Groovy or Kotlin as its language. Explaining the differences between those three is far too broad. You can read up on them on https://maven.apache.org/ and https://gradle.org/. Their use will have no difference on what you can do in Spring Boot, just how you configure the build.

Answer (score 0):

That's not about spring, that is dependencies management.

1. Dependencies : all the source code, API which is nessecerry in your project and make you save time for building your project.
2. A project have many dependencies so we need a tool to manage dependencies.

So we have Gradle - Groovy vs Gradle - Kotlin vs Maven to manage dependencies for your application.

You just need to get that then choose one of your famous (suggest for Maven). Earch of them have different config in project but same target.