What is the key differences between Gradle Groovy Vs Gradle Kotlin Vs Maven? And is there any specific projects that these are best for?
I am new to spring, I want to know the usage of Gradle Kotlin, Gradle Groovy and Maven. Like how they will be used? Is there any specific usage of these three related to projects.? For what kind of projects which can be used for better build?
I am looking forward for a better explanation that helps me to understand how these three work, and what to choose for the projects.

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/78242985/5133585

Gradle and Maven are two popular build tools used to automate your projects' builds instead of writing lengthy commands for compilers.
Based on the specifics of your question, there are the following differences I am aware of:
What are these
Gradle with Groovy is nothing but the Gradle build scripts which are written in Groovy as a language
Gradle with Kotlin is also nothing but the Gradle build scripts which are written in Kotlin as a language
While Maven uses XML for its configs.
There is no difference whether you use Groovy or Kotlin, Gradle will work the same. Since Kotlin is a new emerging and quite popular language people found it more convenient over the Groovy.
Which one is better
While Gradle is faster because it uses build caches and has almost all the benefits that Maven provides and is considered a better choice, since Maven was present from the beginning developers and software engineers sometimes prefer Maven.
Conclusion
It is just a personal preference which one you want to choose.

Kotlin is statically typed, whilst Groovy is not. This means your get type-safety and better code-completion with Kotlin. On the other hand, Groovy is more flexible in some respects due to its dynamic method calling, which Gradle makes use of.

Also, Groovy is bundled with Gradle while Kotlin is not. When using the Kotlin DSL, Gradle will download additional dependencies behind the scenes.
